# How do you use a key to generate new code when using charCodeAt()?

Tags: javascript, fromcharcode

I have been working on my science fair project that is due in 3 days and I need help.  I using charCodeAt(), however I don't know how to write the code that will use the key and charCodeAt() to create a new code. Please help.

Comment: What "new code" do you desire?

Comment: I am making a homemade encryption device, and using the Caesar Cipher as my cipher type. The key in this case would be the number of characters you want to shift the alphabet.  The new code would be the encrypted words, ciphertext.  Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
var plainText = "watergate";
var cipherText = "";
for ( var i = 0; i < plainText.length; i++ )
  cipherText += String.fromCharCode( plainText.charCodeAt(i) + 42 );
```